# FFmpeg 4:3 video with letter box to 16:9 without encode/lossless

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Im reading and trying about this but I do not get it. I have a video in 720x576 in 4:3 and would like put off the letter box and put the video in 16: 9

Anyone knows or can gives me a hint?

Comment: what have you already tried? Why didn't it produce expected results? Questions are expected to show research.

Comment: Most ffmpeg filters for scaling or cropping force recoding, I have also tried with mkvmerge, but I can't find the correct method

Comment: You cannot do it without transcoding. The black bars are encoded in the video, the only way to remove them is to re-encode it after stripping it our frame by frame.

Comment: @Mokubai false, there are methods to do it for videos in h264 and mpeg... am doing right now with a h264 video:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378548/ffmpeg-crop-a-video-without-losing-the-quality

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=crop_left=200:crop_right=1240:crop_top=200:crop_bottom=610 output.mp4

Comment: That's just putting some extra data in to tell the video player to not show areas of the video. Sure it kinda meets criteria but it's not really "cropping" and video players may well ignore or misinterpret it, as is evidenced in the comments to the answer that contains that solution. The bars *are* still there.

Comment: What's wrong with using the h264_metadata bitstream filter as shown in your comment? No other way around it unless you want to just have your player crop it live during playback.